# Navcontroller.navigate() working occasionally only

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Android Navigation Components in my app to navigate to different fragments. I have activity a Activity and three fragments A, B and C. I can navigate from fragment A to B and C easily like this;

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
// Button "A to B" click
navController.navigate(R.id.a_to_b);
//Button "A to C" click
navController.navigate(R.id.a_to_c);
```

This works fine but when I introduce a fullscreen Admob ad between button click and do the same same exact naigation action on OnAdClosed method of ad it sometimes navigates and sometimes does not.(No error in logcat when it does not navigate). The issue is occouring only in android versions below 8 only. What could be causing this ?

Comment: Probably that Navigation actions are consumed/ignored when the NavController has "saved its state" (after onStop)